# My adapter not update correctly my listview option

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have the next problem. When I delete an item from my ListView in my adapter the state of the CheckBox change from item in list, Why? and, how can solve this problem?

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowModel> implements View.OnClickListener {

private ArrayList<RowModel> DataSet;
Context context;

public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<RowModel> data, Context context) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item_main, data);
    this.DataSet = data;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
    Object object = getItem(position);
    RowModel dataRowModel = (RowModel) object;

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.list_checkbox:
            CheckBox checkBox = v.findViewById(R.id.list_checkbox);
            int bool = (checkBox.isChecked()) ? 1 : 0;
            new ListFacade(context).UpdateState(dataRowModel.getRowid(), bool);
            break;
        case R.id.list_delete_button:
            new ListFacade(context).DeleteRow(dataRowModel.getRowid());
            DataSet.remove(object);
            break;
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    updateWidgetToChange();
}
```

if I delete the *item 4*

[image]

the checkbox of *item 5* happens to be selected by the deletion of *item 4*

[image]

EDIT 1: added getView

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the data item for this position
    RowModel dataRowModel = getItem(position);
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag

    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_main, parent, false);
        viewHolder.checkbox = convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_checkbox);
        viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(dataRowModel.isChecked());
        viewHolder.title = convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_title);
        viewHolder.classes = convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_classes);
        viewHolder.rowid = convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_rowid);
        viewHolder.delete_button = convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_delete_button);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.rowid.setText(dataRowModel.getStringRowid());
    viewHolder.title.setText(dataRowModel.getAction());
    viewHolder.classes.setText(dataRowModel.getType());
    viewHolder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(this);
    viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(position);
    viewHolder.delete_button.setOnClickListener(this);
    viewHolder.delete_button.setTag(position);
    // Return the completed view to render on screen
    return convertView;
}
```

Edit 2: Added ListFacade

```
public void UpdateState(int rowid, int bool){
    SQLiteDatabase conn = new SqliteHandler(context).getWritableDatabase();
    String strSQL = "UPDATE TODO_LIST SET CHECKED='"+ bool +"' WHERE ROWID = "+ rowid;
    conn.execSQL(strSQL);
    conn.close();
}

public void DeleteRow(int rowid){
    SQLiteDatabase conn = new SqliteHandler(context).getWritableDatabase();
    conn.delete("TODO_LIST", "ROWID=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(rowid)});
    conn.close();
}
```

Comment: could you please elaborate more

Comment: Could you add the `ListFacade` implementation? Specifically `UpdateState()` and `DeleteRow()`? Side note: Java method and variable names should follow camel case, i.e. `updateState()` and `deleteRow()`.

Comment: ready, but are funtions for sqlite changes

Comment: Check my answer, looks like you are not updating the checkbox's value in getView like i guessed.

Comment: Edited my answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just guessing but I think that you need to get the check box's state updated in getView-method. When you remove the object from dataSet, you need to make sure the isChecked is updated in the getView-method. Now when you remove the one data from dataSet and the list items are updated, the CheckBox's state is not changed.

Do you have something like this in your code?:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    // Other code...
    RowModel model = getItem(position);
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_checkbox);
    cb.setChecked(model.isChecked());
    // ...
}
```

Because I'm seeing that you are not updating the dataset in your CheckBox's click listener.

So you need to add this in there also, or something like this:

```
case R.id.list_checkbox:
        CheckBox checkBox = v.findViewById(R.id.list_checkbox);
        dataRowModel.isChecked(checkBox.isChecked());
        // ... rest of the code
```

Edit:

The problem is that you are only updating the CheckBox when the View (convertView) is null! You need to move that code away from the if (convertView == null) because it gets only called when the View is created and when you call notifyDataSetChanged, the Views are not created again and your if-block is not reached.

Comment: not work, is the same problem. I added get view function

Comment: the checkbox make the change correctly but when I update the views this not change

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: Always happy to help:)

Comment: You edited your answer just as I was typing mine. Good catch!

Comment: I need help with this too, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54637748 (get bundle in widget) if they could review

Comment: Can you accept my answer if you think it was the correct one? Sorry, I can't help you with that because I'm not so familiar with the Android Widgets.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @vilpe89's answer, the problem isn't that you aren't calling `setChecked()` in `getView()`, it's that you're calling it in the wrong spot:

```
viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(dataRowModel.isChecked());
```

You call this line only if `convertView == null`, except that when you update the list `convertView` will not be null. Therefore, to fix your problem, you need to move that line to after the `if else` statement, like so:

```
viewHolder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(this);
viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(dataRowModel.isChecked());
viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(position);
```

Comment: Yeah, I was not aware of that when I first wrote the answer because he was not providing the getView-method's code then. So I just guessed it and then edited when I saw the getView's code.